# How to use eso-pic to print, right-aligned, at the top-right of the page?

Tags: eso-pic

How to use `eso-pic` to print, right-aligned, at the top-right of the page?

The manual can be found here:
http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/eso-pic.pdf

Comment: At the top-right of the sheet of of the text area? And what would you like to print there?

Comment: @Bernard Could be an image, could be text. Could be single-line or multi-line text.

Comment: But *where*, precisely?

Comment: If it would print "This is a sentence." Then the dot "." should be printed at the top-right of the page, everything else before it. Should be a way to fiddle with the exact height afterwards as well :)

Comment: The ‘page’ may mean the sheet of paper or the text area. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Bernard With 'page' I mean the sheet of paper. Vertically speaking, it would be nice if the top line was printed with its top edge right matching the top edge of the page (with an option to fiddle with additional y spacing to bring everything further down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following places the contents like you want them. To move the contents a bit just change the `0pt` to your liking.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG
  {%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth-0pt},\LenToUnit{\paperheight-0pt})
      {%
        \llap % make it overlap to the left from this point
          {%
            \raisebox{-\height} % move it down a bit to make it top-aligned
              {\parbox{5cm}{\blindduck}}% contents
          }%
      }%
  }

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\mbox{}% produces one empty page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{\hspace*{\paperwidth\llap{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{pepe-le-pew2}}}}}}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  \includegraphics{pepe-le-pew2}
\caption{Pepe le Pew in action}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\hspace*{\paperwidth}` semantically?

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz:??? I don't understand. That's how I coded. Could you explain?

Comment: The closing brace isn't after `\paperwidth` but only at the end, giving the entire argument to `\hspace` instead of putting it after `\hspace`.